# C++ pow(400,-9) is giving wrong answer

Tags: c++, math, pow

```
double testpower;

testpower = pow(400,-9);
```

`testpower` giving me `3.8146972656250003e-024` which is different calculator output of `4E-7`

Anyone have any idea why??

Comment: Do you think the correct is 4E-7?

Comment: `pow` is correct. Check with Windows' `calc.exe` or [Google](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=400%5E(-9))

Comment: 4E-7 would be 4*10^-9, not 1/(400^9), which is what `pow(400,-9)` will evaluate to. `pow` is giving the right answer for the input.

Comment: @wolfPack88 4*10^-9 acually would be 4E-9, you meant 400*10^-9. Good catch

Comment: @Slava: Yeah, typo: meant 400*10^-9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> calculator output of 4E-7

You entered the wrong calculation into your calculator.

You entered 400×10<sup>-9</sup>, instead of 400<sup>-9</sup>.
*These are absolutely not the same thing!*

The C++ program is correct: `pow(400, -9)` calculates 400<sup>-9</sup>, which is approximately 3.815×10<sup>-24</sup>.

Here is some further reading for you:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: He entered wrong calculation or does not understand what `pow()` calculates

Comment: @Slava Yes, that's what my answer says.

Comment: No, you said that he entered wrong calculation. I said that he may entered correct calculation but does not understand what `pow()` calculates

Comment: @Slava Did you even read this answer before commenting on it? It explains (a) what he entered in his calculator, and (b) what `pow()` does. Both possible confusion is covered.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I believe @Slava was referring to your first sentence, `You entered the wrong calculation into your calculator.` Technically, it should say, `Either you entered the wrong calculation into your calculator, or you don't understand what pow does.` I'll stop being a pedant and move along now.

Comment: @wolfPack88: That's not being "pedantic" (this is!): it's requesting _additional_ exposition, not pointing out an error in existing exposition (as no such error exists). The OP _did_ enter the wrong calculation into his calculator, whether he thought that was the correct one or not. It doesn't matter. There is no need to spell out every possible way that the OP may have misunderstood the situation: I have provided an explanation to cover each eventuality. I don't see the need for this fuss.

Answer (score 1):

`4E-7` seems like you accidentally input `400 * 10^-9` or  `400E-9`.

You're looking for `400^-9`, which should give `3.8146972656250003e-024`.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting  3.8146972656250003e-024 is completely correct. Maybe your calculator does not have that precission and that is why you are getting that error. Try to do 1/400^9.

Comment: Calculator precision is not the culprit, as wolfPack88 catches 4E-7 is exactly 400*10^-9 so OP just used his calculator incorrectly, or does not understand what `pow()` does

Answer (score 0):

I just tested 400^(-9) on the Windows calculator tool and I got the same output as your program. I think the program is fine, it may be your manual calculation that is the problem here.